# How to expand an image by Hover over in HTML?

Tags: html, css

This code works on desktop but it's not mobile responsive at all. When I load the webpage on an Android and hover over an image to expand, the image width doesn't fit my mobile screen and goes beyond it.

**HTML-**

```
<img src="html_res/image001.JPG" id="image" class="images">
```

**CSS-**

```
#image{
    height:250px;
    width:450px;
}

#image:hover{
    height:600px;
    width:950px;
}
```

How to make this code mobile responsive?

Comment: I think you mean touch because you said it was mobile. If so, I think you can use ':active'.

Comment: what do you expect to happen to the height of the image on hover if the width of the viewport is less than 950px? it should always be 600px?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=hover+active+mobile+css+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the px units and use percentage (%), using percentage will expand the image according to the size of the screen. Also put the meta tag which makes the page responsive